# Optimistic Concurrency while Updating Records in EF 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, insert-update, optimistic-concurrency

I received this exception while debugging in VS 2012

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key.

```
//_dbSet declaration: 

    private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbSet;


//Method parameter

    public virtual void Update(T entity)


//method fragment   



 public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        if (Entities == null) return;

        var entry = Entities.Entry(entity);

        switch (entry.State)
        {
            case EntityState.Modified:
                var currentValues = entry.CurrentValues.Clone();
                entry.Reload();
                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Detached:
                        Entities.Entry(entry).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        break;
                    default:
                        entry.Reload();
                        entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(currentValues);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case EntityState.Detached:
                _dbSet.Attach(entity); /*Here is the thing*/
                entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
                break;
        }
        Entities.Commit();
    }
```

I have spent almost a week trying to solve optimistic concurrency with these patterns:
DbFactory, Unit of Work, DI, Generic Repository, without getting results.

Comment: The title of this question has nothing to do with the question

Answer (score 0):

I believe the exception message is clear enough:

An entity with the same key (that is, an entity that maps to the same database record) has already been loaded and attached in the target `DbSet`.

What you decide to do in that case is entirely up to you:

- You can get the already loaded equivalent entry and modify the values of the attached equivalent to match the `entity` instance (or anything more complicated);
- You can detach the equivalent loaded entry and attach your parameter `entity` instead;
- You can just skip over it;

Answer (score 0):

The code smells bad;

The first `switch` statement uses the `entry.State` and checking whether the entity is in modified state or in detached state; then in the modified case , a new switch statement is created to check whether the entity is detached or in other state.

The exception states nothing about the optimistic concurrency; instead it states that you are trying to attach an entity to the object context and an entity with the same key already exists in the context.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank all of whom dedicated a bit of their precious time to my headake.
Here is a new post clearifying my final solution for concurrent Update method in Generic Repository pattern. Nothing was lost thanks to this article: 
[Seeking Entity's Key by Attribute Along](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284055/how-to-retrieve-an-ef-4-code-first-entitys-key-by-the-attribute-alone-before)

> That was very useful: [RoccoC5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181483/roccoc5)

---

```
private object GetKeyValue(T entity)
    {
        var key =
            typeof(T).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(
                p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), true).Length != 0);
        return (key != null) ? key.GetValue(entity, null) : null;
    }
```

public virtual void Update(T entity)
        {
            if (Entities == null) return;

```
        var key = GetKeyValue(entity);
        var originalEntity = _dbSet.Find(key);
        Entities.Entry(originalEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
        Entities.Commit();
   }
```